# Failed to create flutter app after follow the tutorial

Tags: android, gradle, flutter

I am follow the flutter tutorial to create flutter app. first, use flutter command `flutter create myflutter` to initialize. then  I execute `flutter run` got some `gradle` resolve dependencies error, it show a `405` network eror when i visit `dl.google.com`,then I change the `bulid.gradle` file to visit an normal websit,I still failed.the follow code is my config:
android\build.gradle：

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.71'
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'http://maven.aliyun.com/nexus/content/groups/public/' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'http://maven.aliyun.com/nexus/content/groups/public/' }
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

the error message:

```
Launching lib\main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
Initializing gradle...
Resolving dependencies...
* Error running Gradle:
ProcessException: Process "C:\Users\linla\AndroidStudioProjects\flutter_app2\android\gradlew.bat" exited abnormally:

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0.
     Required by:
         project :
      > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0.
         > Could not get resource 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.1.0/gradle-3.1.0.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.1.0/gradle-3.1.0.pom'. Received status code 405 from server: Method Not Allowed
      > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0.
         > Could not get resource 'http://maven.aliyun.com/nexus/content/groups/public/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.1.0/gradle-3.1.0.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'http://maven.aliyun.com/nexus/content/groups/public/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.1.0/gradle-3.1.0.pom'.
               > maven.aliyun.com:80 failed to respond
   > Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.2.71.
     Required by:
         project :
      > Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.2.71.
         > Could not get resource 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-gradle-plugin/1.2.71/kotlin-gradle-plugin-1.2.71.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-gradle-plugin/1.2.71/kotlin-gradle-plugin-1.2.71.pom'. Received status code 405 from server: Method Not Allowed
      > Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.2.71.
         > Could not get resource 'http://maven.aliyun.com/nexus/content/groups/public/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-gradle-plugin/1.2.71/kotlin-gradle-plugin-1.2.71.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'http://maven.aliyun.com/nexus/content/groups/public/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-gradle-plugin/1.2.71/kotlin-gradle-plugin-1.2.71.pom'.
               > maven.aliyun.com:80 failed to respond

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2s
  Command: C:\Users\linla\AndroidStudioProjects\flutter_app2\android\gradlew.bat app:properties

Finished with error: Please review your Gradle project setup in the android/ folder.
```

`flutter doctor -v`  log message

```
G:\app\myflutter>flutter doctor -v
[√] Flutter (Channel beta, v0.11.3, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.16299.547], locale zh-CN)
    • Flutter version 0.11.3 at C:\dep\flutter
    • Framework revision 72bf075e8d (11 days ago), 2018-11-09 20:36:17 -0800
    • Engine revision 5646e86a6f
    • Dart version 2.1.0 (build 2.1.0-dev.9.3 9c07fb64c4)

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK 28.0.3)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\linla\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
    • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
    • Platform android-28, build-tools 28.0.3
    • Java binary at: E:\developeSoftware\AS\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1136-b06)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Android Studio (version 3.2)
    • Android Studio at E:\developeSoftware\AS
    • Flutter plugin version 29.1.1
    • Dart plugin version 181.5540.11
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1136-b06)

[√] Connected device (1 available)
    • Android SDK built for x86 • emulator-5554 • android-x86 • Android 9 (API 28) (emulator)

• No issues found!
```

it may be my version error? or other config error?

Comment: `Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.1.0/gradle-3.1.0.pom'. Received status code 405 from server: Method Not Allowed`

Comment: I am in CN,it has GFW,I can't visit GOOGLE resource,So I change to other mirror ,but still no work

Comment: when I visit this url in my browser `http://maven.aliyun.com/nexus/content/groups/public/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-gradle-plugin/1.2.71/kotlin-gradle-plugin-1.2.71.pom` , I can dowload the file,so I am confuse now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change url like this:

```
....
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://maven.aliyun.com/repository/google/' }
    }
.
.
.
allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://maven.aliyun.com/repository/google/' }
    }
}
```

Comment: still got 405 error  ` > Could not GET 'https://maven.aliyun.com/repository/google/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.1.0/gradle-3.1.0.pom'. Received status code 405 from server: Method Not Allowed`

Comment: at last, I uninstall my Android Studio and Clean all the config. reinstall Android Studio Keep the network still is ok (vpn) .then it's ok Now. thanks!